# Appending inner contents of a container without losing binding in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, append

I'm trying to append the contents of a container from one to the other without losing any sort of binding and I'm scratching my head wondering why it's so difficult :D

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="field">
         <label>Password</label>
         <input type="username" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="field">
         <label>Password</label>
         <input type="password" />
    </div>
</div>

// This puts the actual container in, I need the inner contents of it
$('.container').eq(0).append($('.container').eq(1));

// This loses any sort of binding that applies to what I'm moving
$('.container').eq(0).append($('.container').eq(1).html());

// This screws up the HTML
$('.container').eq(0).append($('*', $(container).eq(1)));
```

Seems like such a simple and common task but I've got no idea how to get around this? My first answer would be to wrap the content in another container and move that instead.

What d'ya think? Am I going mad or is this impossible? :D

Comment: `.html()` serializes the elements to a string, which is why the 2nd attempt loses event bindings. I'm not sure why the 1st wouldn't work, if the 2nd does, aside from event bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
$('.container').eq(0).append($('.container').eq(1).children());
```

[JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/oxudig/2/edit) - You'll notice the change function still works on the appended field.

Comment: Aggh! Yes of course :D Thanks so much... I'm not quite sure why I didn't think of that before 8-)